# MahApps.Metro Application

Tags: c#, wpf, transition, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to implement something with the MahApps.Metro style. In the demo there are always those transitions if I click on another tab, but I think this is a little but too much. I found transitions in the documentation, but how do I manage the transitions of those tabs? Is that possible in some way?

I have been looking through the code of the demo, but I couldn't figure out how to control the transitions of the tabs itself. So everytime the content changes there is this transiton. Either I put in a custom transition or turn it off. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MahApps.Metro, there are a few different types of TabControls. The one you're looking for is the one called MetroTabControl, not MetroAnimatedTabControl.

MetroTabControl is your regular TabControl with the Metro style, minus the transitions.